# Mixing external and internal cell referencing in formula

Tags: excel

I don't have a decent way of explaining this but I'm going to try. Sorry.
I have two documents. I'm linking one document to the other to present some info from that first document into the second one inside a specific cell.

Let's say I want the data from `B2` from my first sheet. Is the only way to do this is by typing `B2` into the formula itself or can I create a variable and have that space be filled in by putting the appropriate cell number into another cell? If I want it to reference `B2` from the external sheet, can I type `B2` into a specific cell on the page and that cell is defined as `my_number` and I can place that variable `my_number` into the `importrange` formula?

Or can I not mix external and internal referencing? I tried to search for something similar online but I didn't have a lot of luck.

If this is still not explained very well, this is kind of a visual:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("mydocsheet.com/spreadsheet", "Sheet1![my_number]") instead of 
=IMPORTRANGE("mydocsheet.com/spreadsheet", "Sheet1!B2")
```

Comment: Are you using VBA here? Please specify the language, use a tag for the language and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Those are quoted strings representing cell range references; not cell range references. You should have no problem using concatenated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Those are quoted strings representing cell range references; not true cell range references. You should have no problem using concatenated strings. With *B2* in a named cell called *my_number*,

```
=IMPORTRANGE("mydocsheet.com/spreadsheet", "Sheet1!" & Sheet1!my_number")
```

Comment: Oh, that was a lot simpler than I thought. Thank you!